# Revolution Slider - is there an stand alone editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I like the revolution slider, but how can I edit the slides in an UI like in WordPress, but without using WordPress, magento?

I want to get the jQuery code only.

Is that possible? Maybe with another slider?

Comment: You should ask it to plugin's author maybe

Comment: It's right on the homepage -> goodies -> slider versions ->[jquery](http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-responsive-jquery-plugin/2580848?ref=themepunch&ref=themepunch&clickthrough_id=300487473&redirect_back=true)

Comment: Ok, thank you, I ask on website for an editor. Thougt You know another one maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Now they have: **[Slider Revolution Jquery Visual Editor Addon](http://codecanyon.net/item/slider-revolution-jquery-visual-editor-addon/13934907)**

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this at the moment.

I am working currently to make it available without wordperss but it is hard work. 
Let me know if you will find other solution.

Comment: Thank You for you answer and developing. I will tell you. :-)